# Is there a way to make partial grouping in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a list of logins and I need to group specific logins into one row/ SO the change should look smth like this:

- `NAME   VALUE`
- `spec1  1`
- `1      2`
- `2      0`
- `spec2  2`
- `3      3`
- `4      1`
- `spec3  4`

---->

- `NAME   VALUE`
- `spec   7`
- `1      2`
- `2      0`
- `3      3`
- `4      1`

P.S. I want to make a SELECT and not to change original table.

Comment: select NAME,VALUE from table ->groupBy name you could try this.. but im not sure if i know what you want to accomplish

Comment: would suggest to do everything else outside of the code like a if($object->name === 'spec'.$i) inside of a foreach and rename it there

Comment: I want to have smth like this:
`if name like spec%:
name becomes "spec"
then
group by name`

Answer (score 2):

```sql
SELECT CASE WHEN name LIKE 'spec%'
            THEN 'spec'
            ELSE name
            END AS name,
       SUM(value) AS value
FROM tablename
GROUP BY 1;
```